# AWS and SSL and option to modify an EC2 instance

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

If i understood well, a standard SSL certificat is only for 1 server.

I have an EC2 instance, with an SSL certificate.

If i modify this instance, to change from a type of instance to another for example, i think amazon will take a snapshot and restore this snapshot on the new instance automatically.

My question is : in this case, does the ssl certificate still correct ?

thanks in advance for your replies

Frederic

Answer (score 0):

Ssl certificate has been issued to the domain name(or IP address).
So, if your domain name(or IP address) has not change, the ssl certificate can continue to use.